# Javascript prototype checking differentiate "function declaration" with "function expression", why?

Tags: javascript, function, expression, prototype, declaration

First of all, I tried

```
var o = {};
var Derived = function () {}
Derived.prototype = o;
var o2 = new Derived();
console.log(o.isPrototypeOf(o2));
```

It prints "true"

Then I tried function expression as below:

```
var o = function(){};            //difference 1
var Derived = function () {}
Derived.prototype = new o();
var o2 = new Derived();          //difference 2
console.log(o.isPrototypeOf(o2));
```

It prints "false"

I suppose that both

```
"o={}" declares an object
"new o()" declares an object.
```

But why they differ in final results?

Comment: I thought I was going to be smart and say you needed `Derived.prototype = Object.create(o);` but I have no idea why this makes it work or why it is different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when assigning an object to a variable, you're  a**ssigning by reference**, meaning that **Derived.prototype** is equal to **o** even after you're assigning **o** to **Derived.prototype**. It is a reference to the object **o**, which is why you get true when you validate the prototype, because **Derived.prototype** (which is the real prototype) is equal to **o**.

When you use **new**, you're creating a new object that isn't **o** anymore. **o** is only the **constructor** allowing creation of this new object. So **o** isn't the prototype, **o** and **Derived.prototype** aren't the same. **o.prototype** is the prototype. You can simplify your example this way to target what the real difference is:

```
x = {};
y = x;
console.log(x === y);
```

vs:

```
x = function(){};
y = new x();
console.log(x === y, x.prototype.isPrototypeOf(y));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example o is a concrete js object which is created by a mechanism similar to `new Object()`

Whereas in the second example, it is a function expression. Its not the same as an ordinary js object.

Moreover `isProtoType` call you are doing with `o` is as a function object. Not a concrete one. Whereas `o2` is a concrete object as opposed to a function object.